# C# Overriding abstract methods (include input parameters)

Tags: c#, class, interface, abstract-class

It is possible in C# do something like this

```
public absctract class ImportBase()
{
   public abstract void CreateDocument();
}
public class UsingOne : ImportBase
{
   public override bool CreateDocument(string name)
   {
      return null;
   }
}
```

I want have some Base class, which only have some methods,but in derived class i need change inputs parameters and inside of method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you want to minimize the duplicate code on your **derived classes**. Basically it's not possible to have an override of a different signature but surely you can refactor your code where you can keep the possible duplicate code in the base class and use it on your derived classes.

```
public absctract class ImportBase()
{
   //Making this protected here
   protected virtual void CreateDocument() 
   {
      //Your CreateDocument code
   };
}

public class UsingOne : ImportBase
{
   private override void CreateDocument()
   {
      // Override this if you have different CreateDocument for your different
      // for different derived class.
   }
   public bool CreateDocument(string name)
   {
      // Do whatever you need to do with name parameter.
      base.CreateDocument();
      // Do whatever you need to do with name parameter.
      return true; // return false;
   }
}
```

You can create instance of `UsingOne` and invoke `CreateDocument(string name)`

Comment: The override would have to be protected rather than private.

Answer (score 4):

You're not overriding the method. The point of having an abstract (or virtual) method is that given any `ImportBase`, I should be able to call

```
importBase.CreateDocument();
```

That's clearly *not* the case with `UsingOne`, as it needs more information. So you're really trying to tie your caller to `UsingOne`, not just `ImportBase` - at which point you've lost the benefits of polymorphism.

To override a method, the implementation has to have the same signature, basically.

Comment: I understand. Find way to have only prescription of methods, and derived class say what the methods need and what returns

Answer (score 1):

nope. signature must be same on the derived class. i suggest to use builder pattern.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern